# How to cast Oracle column CHAR(1 Byte) to java String Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have this case, in oracle data base I have a column char(1), I get in java with hibernate value 1 in my property, but in db it havs 'A', what can i do?

mycolumn CHAR(1 Byte);

@Column (name = "mycolumn",  columnDefinition = "CHAR")
    private String mycolumn;

It return 1 but in db it have 'A'

Comment: What does it return when the db has 'B'

Comment: I´m, sorry to delayed, this case was my mistake. Im work in a group big then... in database someone create one view and became the value to 1....when I´ll check the data base can see that...

Comment: Glad it worked out